# Display result rows vertically in MS Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Using DBeaver, a GUI database client, i can press tab in the results window to switch to a vertical display mode focused on a single row. How do i do the same in SSMS?

[image]

Comment: I'm going to say that I don't believe this is possible in SSMS, however by commenting here I'm also going to catch anyone's follow-up saying how it can be done!